# "Item not found in this collection" when trying to set the Shape on IFeatureBuffer

Tags: arcobjects, shapefile, buffer, features

I'm working on code to open a 3rd party data file and convert it into a collection of features in a custom layer based on FeatureLayer. I have had no issue importing the data itself (nodal data for each 'cell' as a feature, such as elevation).

Because the data files are on average rather large (10k+ cells), I'm using a cursor implementation with an IFeatureBuffer that is filled with each cell one at a time. However, when I try to set the geometry of the cell via IFeatureBuffer like so,

IGeometry cellGeometry = getCellGeometry(cell);

featureBuffer.Shape = cellGeometry;

I subsequently get the error "Item not found in this collection" called on the second line. My first thought was that I was creating the cell geometry incorrectly in some way, so I tested it by creating a simple point as the geometry. This failed with the same error. I next thought it might be an issue with ZAware. I tried setting it to both ((IZAware)cellGeometry).ZAware = true; and ((IZAware)cellGeometry).ZAware = false; with the same issue both times.

I'm thinking it might have to do with how the fields in the FeatureClass were setup, but I'm quite stuck at the moment.

UPDATE:

I've tried updating how the fields are created to fix any issues that may exist therein, and the issue remains. The fields are generated like so,

```
    {
        if (this.ImportedField == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        IObjectClassDescription fcDesc;
        if (this.DatasetType == esriDatasetType.esriDTTable)
            fcDesc = new ObjectClassDescriptionClass();
        else
            fcDesc = new FeatureClassDescriptionClass();

        IFields fields = fcDesc.RequiredFields;
        IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)fields;

        //Setup shape field
        IField shapeField = fields.Field[fields.FindField("Shape")];
        IFieldEdit shapeFieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)shapeField;
        shapeFieldEdit.Name_2 = "SHAPE";
        shapeFieldEdit.AliasName_2 = "SHAPE";
        shapeFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry;
        shapeFieldEdit.Length_2 = 0;
        shapeFieldEdit.Precision_2 = 0;
        shapeFieldEdit.Scale_2 = 0;
        shapeFieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
        shapeFieldEdit.Required_2 = true;
        shapeFieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;
        shapeFieldEdit.Domain_2 = null;
        shapeFieldEdit.DomainFixed_2 = true;
        shapeFieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = BuildGeometryDefinition(BuildGenericSpatialReference(true), esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon, true, false);

        var fieldNames = this.ImportedField.CoordinateData.ScalarData.Select(nodeData => nodeData.Name).ToList();
        fieldNames.AddRange(this.ImportedField.CellData.ScalarData.Select(cellData => cellData.Name));

        //Add fields from ImportedField
        foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
        {
            IFieldEdit fieldEdit = new FieldClass();
            fieldEdit.Length_2 = 1;
            fieldEdit.Name_2 = fieldName;
            fieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeSingle;
            fieldsEdit.AddField(fieldEdit);
        }

        return fields as IFields;
    }
```

Comment: FYI, This issue isn't related to my implementation of a custom layer. In test cases where I simply add the FeatureClass to a generic FeatureLayer, the same thing occurs.

Comment: Are you able to interactively edit the featureclass using arcmap?

Comment: Yes, I can Add/Delete fields from the FeatureClass in ArcMap and ArcScene without any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution. For whatever reason, the Shape field must be set before any of the other fields.

This does **not** work:

```
IGeometry cellGeometry = getCellGeometry(cell);
featureBuffer.Shape = cellGeometry;
```

But for some reason this **does**:

```
featureBuffer.Shape = cellGeometry;
IGeometry cellGeometry = getCellGeometry(cell);
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be required, so I added a bug tag to your question.

Comment: This works for me as well @ 10.3.1

Answer (score 1):

When setting up geometric fields for feature classes, you have to define the entire IGeometryDef for it, and be sure that it is correct.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is the exact problem, but here's a taste how I build fields.

My guess is that you are trying to access the geometry field whereas it doesn't fully exists.

This code I use works:

```
    public static IField2 BuildGeometryField(ISpatialReference spatialReference,esriGeometryType geometryType,bool hasZ, bool hasM)
    {
        IGeometryDef geometryDefinition = GeometryDefinitionBuilder.BuildGeometryDefinition(spatialReference,
            geometryType,hasZ,hasM);

        IField2 field = BuildField("SHAPE","SHAPE",esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry,0,0,0,false,true,null,false,geometryDefinition);

        return field;
    }

  public static IField2 BuildField(string fieldName, string fieldAlias, esriFieldType fieldType, int fieldLength, int fieldPrecision, int fieldScale,
        bool isNullable, bool isRequired, IDomain fieldDomain, bool isDomainFixed, IGeometryDef geometryDefinition)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
            throw new ArgumentException(GeometryMessages.FieldNameNullOrEmpty);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldAlias))
            fieldAlias = fieldName;

        if (fieldType == esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString)
        {
            fieldScale = 0;
            fieldPrecision = 0;
        }

        IField2 field = new FieldClass();
        IFieldEdit2 fieldEdit = field as IFieldEdit2;

        fieldEdit.Name_2 = fieldName;
        fieldEdit.AliasName_2 = fieldAlias;
        fieldEdit.Type_2 = fieldType;
        fieldEdit.Length_2 = fieldLength;

        fieldEdit.Precision_2 = fieldPrecision;
        fieldEdit.Scale_2 = fieldScale;

        fieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = isNullable;
        fieldEdit.Required_2 = isRequired;

        fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;

        if (fieldDomain != null)
        {
            fieldEdit.Domain_2 = fieldDomain;
            fieldEdit.DomainFixed_2 = isDomainFixed;
        }

        if (geometryDefinition != null)
            fieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = geometryDefinition;

        return field;
    }
```

Comment: I do essentially this, but I do it via editing (I generate the fields using RequiredField). Could that be the issue?