# "The Fields collection did not contain an expected geometry field" (ArcGIS 10)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, c#

I am writing a fairly simple application to build simple polylines.

I got most of the application working for the most part, but this part is just baffling me to no end and there is nothing I can find about this problem, so maybe I am alone on this.

This is the code:

```
        IFeatureClassDescription fcDescrip = new FeatureClassDescription() as IFeatureClassDescription;
        IObjectClassDescription objDescrip = (IObjectClassDescription)fcDescrip;

        IFieldsEdit fields = (IFieldsEdit)objDescrip.RequiredFields;

        IFieldEdit geoField = (IFieldEdit)fields.get_Field(fields.FindField(fcDescrip.ShapeFieldName));

        IGeometryDefEdit geoDefField = (IGeometryDefEdit)geoField.GeometryDef;

        geoDefField.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline;
        geoDefField.SpatialReference_2 = spatialReference;
        geoDefField.HasM_2 = true;
        geoDefField.GridCount_2 = 1;
        geoDefField.set_GridSize(0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fields.get_Field(i).Name);
            if (fields.get_Field(i).Name == "SHAPE")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fields.get_Field(i).GeometryDef.GeometryType);
            }
        }

        UID uidCL = new UID();
        uidCL.Generate();
        UID uidEXT = new UID();
        uidEXT.Generate();

        IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(m_name, (IFields)fields, uidCL, uidEXT, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, string.Empty, string.Empty);
        IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
```

It tells me that it doesn't contain a geometry field... even though it clearly does because it tells me what shape it has in there.

I tried using add_Field, but it does the same thing (oddly) if I do. It clearly updates 'fields' since I had it output the type before and after and it changes from polygon to polyline.

I looked at [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/item-not-found-in-this-collection-when-trying-to-set-the-shape-on-ifeaturebuff) and I tried defining everything, but it still gives the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using the the FeatureClassDescription? It is intended to be used when implementing class extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define ShapeFieldName parameter when you call CreateFeatureClass function. In your case, you'll have to set it to "SHAPE".

**Change this:**

```
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(m_name, (IFields)fields, uidCL, uidEXT, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

**to this:**

```
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(m_name, (IFields)fields, uidCL, uidEXT, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "SHAPE", string.Empty);
```